# Split matrices in R

Tags: r

I am trying to split a matrix along the rows but not sure how to do it. For example if I have a NxM matrix but want to split the matrix such that I get n (N/n)xM matrices, how would I do that?

So if I had a matrix X:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   21
 [2,]    2   22
 [3,]    3   23
 [4,]    4   24
 [5,]    5   25
 [6,]    6   26
 [7,]    7   27
 [8,]    8   28
 [9,]    9   29
[10,]   10   30
[11,]   11   31
[12,]   12   32
[13,]   13   33
[14,]   14   34
[15,]   15   35
[16,]   16   36
[17,]   17   37
[18,]   18   38
[19,]   19   39
[20,]   20   40`
```

The output of a function block(X,n) if n = 2 would be

```
[[1]]

       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   21
 [2,]    2   22
 [3,]    3   23
 [4,]    4   24
 [5,]    5   25
 [6,]    6   26
 [7,]    7   27
 [8,]    8   28
 [9,]    9   29
[10,]   10   30

[[2]]

       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   11   31
 [2,]   12   32
 [3,]   13   33
 [4,]   14   34
 [5,]   15   35
 [6,]   16   36
 [7,]   17   37
 [8,]   18   38
 [9,]   19   39
[10,]   20   40
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a grouping column to split

```
n <- 10
grp <- (seq_len(nrow(X)) - 1) %/% n + 1
split(as.data.frame(X), grp)
```

---

Or use index to subset the rows

```
lapply(seq(1, nrow(X), by =  n), function(i) X[i:(i+n -1), ])
```

#### data

```
X <- matrix(1:40, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: @RyanChan The `nrow(X)/n` doesn't work with the example with `n <- 10`  If `n <- 2`, then with your edit, it would be `lapply(seq(1, nrow(X), by = nrow(X)/n), function(i) X[i:(i + 9), ])`

Comment: Sorry you're right, I think you would need X[i:(i+nrow(X)/n - 1),]